# gRpc sending heartbeat - client/server

Tags: c#, client-server, grpc

I am very new to gRpc and have started exploring their basics(in C#). I would like to get guidance on how we can send heart beats to check if client/server is still connected and take recovery actions in case they are disconnected. Any example or reference to any documents/articles will be helpful to get me started. Thanks!

Comment: This is not a valid question for stackoverflow, please read the help on what you can and cannot ask here.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the gRPC [Health Checking Protocol](https://github.com/grpc/grpc/blob/master/doc/health-checking.md).

It's a straightforward protobuf that describes a mechanism by which a client can check whether a server is available and whether services hosted on the server are healthy. The service includes a `Watch` method that provides heatbeats.

You could extend e.g. the `Watch` method or the `HealthCheckRequest` message with a periodicity property to provide clients with a way to define the frequency of messages they require.